# Unique constraint violation thrown by sonarqube 5.6 analysis

Tags: xml, gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.6

I've upgraded to sonarqube-5.6 and it seems to be working ok. One analysis is failing repeatedly though and the logs give this error.

```
016.07.28 21:57:03 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task AVYzS8S3-v6iS1lU8Vlb
org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitException: Visit failed for Component {key=XXX:src/test/resources,type=DIRECTORY}  located XXX(type=PROJECT)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitException.rethrowOrWrap(VisitException.java:44) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:52) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitChildren(PathAwareCrawler.java:87) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitImpl(PathAwareCrawler.java:70) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:50) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.PersistComponentsStep.execute(PersistComponentsStep.java:77) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeSteps(ComputationStepExecutor.java:64) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:52) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.report.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:75) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:81) [sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:56) [sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:35) [sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (XXX.PROJECTS_KEE) violated

### The error may involve org.sonar.db.component.ComponentMapper.insert-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: INSERT INTO projects (kee, deprecated_kee, uuid, project_uuid, module_uuid, module_uuid_path, name, long_name,     qualifier, scope, language, description, root_id, path, copy_resource_id, person_id, enabled,     created_at, authorization_updated_at)     VALUES (?, ?, ?,     ?, ?, ?,     ?, ?, ?, ?,     ?, ?,     ?, ?, ?,     ?,     ?,     ?, ?)
### Cause: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (XXX.PROJECTS_KEE) violated

    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:26) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:154) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:141) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:51) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.insert(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonar.db.component.ComponentDao.insert(ComponentDao.java:278) ~[sonar-db-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.PersistComponentsStep$PersistComponentStepsVisitor.persistComponent(PersistComponentsStep.java:171) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.PersistComponentsStep$PersistComponentStepsVisitor.persistAndPopulateCache(PersistComponentsStep.java:163) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.PersistComponentsStep$PersistComponentStepsVisitor.visitDirectory(PersistComponentsStep.java:135) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitNode(PathAwareCrawler.java:102) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visitImpl(PathAwareCrawler.java:67) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.PathAwareCrawler.visit(PathAwareCrawler.java:50) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

EDIT: further investigation shows that removing the XML plugin prevents this error from occurring. The repository contains a single xml file `src/test/resources/logback-test.xml` and the offending directory is present in the `sonar.tests` property. This seems like it must be a defect to me.